# Javascript Collision (Not Collision Detection)

Tags: javascript, collision

I'm trying to make a platforming game, and I've been working on the collision for the past 2 weeks. The collision detection is working, but the collision itself (as in, keeping the player out of the tile) is not, no matter what I try. I've tried looking up how to do this, but all I'm finding is how to do the detection part, which I already have done. What do I do after I detect collision?
It was written from scratch, and the player is rectangular, and so are the tiles.
Here's the basic code:

```
var Player = function(hue, x, y, xSize, ySize, health) {
    this.hue = hue;
    this.position = new PVector(x, y);
    this.originalPosition = new PVector(x, y);
    //this.previousPosition = new PVector(x, y);
    //this.ppp = new PVector(x, y);
    //this.virtualPosition = new PVector(x, y);
    //this.predictedPosition = new PVector(x, y);
    this.velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    //this.predictedVelocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    this.acceleration = new PVector(0, 0);
}
/*Player.prototype.testCollision = function(tile) {
    if (this.predictedPosition.y < tile.position.y + tile.size.y && this.predictedPosition.y + this.size.y > tile.size.y && this.predictedPosition.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x && this.predictedPosition.x + tile.size.x > tile.position.x) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};*/
Player.prototype.ifColliding = function(tile) {
     if (this.position.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x && this.position.x + tile.size.x > tile.position.x) {
        /*if (this.position.x + this.size.x > tile.position.x) {
            this.position.set(tile.position.x - this.size.x, this.position.y);
        } else if (this.position.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x) {
            this.position.set(tile.position.x + tile.size.x, this.position.y);
        }*/
        this.velocity.set(0, this.velocity.y);
        //this.acceleration.set(0, this.acceleration.y);
        /*if (this.ppp.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x && this.ppp.x + tile.size.x > tile.position.x) {
           if (this.ppp.x + this.size.x > tile.position.x) {
                this.position.set(tile.position.x - this.size.x, this.position.y);
            } else if (this.ppp.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x) {
                this.position.set(tile.position.x + tile.size.x, this.position.y);
            } 
        } else if (this.previousPosition.x < tile.position.x + tile.size.x && this.previousPosition.x + tile.size.x > tile.position.x) {
            this.position.set(this.ppp.x, this.position.y);
        } else {
            this.position.set(this.previousPosition.x, this.position.y);
        }*/
    }
    if (this.position.y < tile.position.y + tile.size.y && this.position.y + this.size.y > tile.size.y) {
        this.velocity.set(this.velocity.x, 0);
        this.acceleration.set(this.acceleration.x, 0);
        this.yColliding = true;
        /*if (this.position.y + this.size.y > tile.position.y) {
            this.position.set(this.position.x, tile.position.y - this.size.y);
            rect(0, 20, 0, 0);
        } else if (this.position.y < tile.position.y + tile.size.y) {
            this.position.set(this.position.x, tile.position.y + tile.size.y);
            rect(20, 20, 0, 0);
        }*/
    }
}
Player.prototype.update = function(tiles) {
    //this.ppp.set(this.previousPosition.x, this.previousPosition.y);
    //this.previousPosition.set(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    /*this.predictedVelocity.set(this.velocity.x, this.velocity.y);
    this.predictedVelocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.virtualPosition.set(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    this.virtualPosition.add(this.velocity);
    this.predictedPosition.set(this.virtualPosition.x, this.virtualPosition.y);
    this.predictedPosition.add(this.predictedVelocity);
    var collDcted = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        if (this.testCollision(tiles[i], true) === false) {
             collDcted = false;
        }
    }*/
    //if (collDcted) {
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    //}
}
```

The commented out code is failed attempts. The non-commented code is the closest I could get it to working.

Comment: What is your player - just a simple rectangular sprite? It's probably just restrict the player's position so that their bounding box doesn't enter the tile and cancel any momentum they have in that direction, but will depend on how you've modeled all of this. Have you written this from scratch, are you building on a framework?

Comment: Hi, @thegeniusyosh, will you please edit your question to elaborate on what specific code question you are trying to solve, including what you have tried already?

Comment: Store the player's last position.  If their new position is invalid, set it to the last valid position.  But, as above, we can't help if you don't post any code.  Please do not just post a bucket load of code.  Post a small piece of code that demonstrates your specific issue.  Read how to create a **[mcve]**

Comment: I added the code and other details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample collision I made:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <body> 
        <p id="Health">Health</p>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="480" style = "border:1px solid gray"></canvas>
<script>
    // Adding keyboard evt listener
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyReleased);
    
    //defining canvas
    var canvas;
    var canvasContext;
    
    //defining Player variables
    var PLAYER_X = 100;
    var PLAYER_Y = 100;
    var PLAYER_WIDTH = 20;
    var PLAYER_HEIGHT = 20;            
    var PLAYER_HEALTH = 100;
    
    //defining keypress codes
    var KEY_LEFT = 37;
    var KEY_RIGHT = 39;
    var KEY_UP = 38;
    var KEY_DOWN = 40;
    
    //variables used to test movement
    var keyHeld_Up = false;
    var keyHeld_Down = false;
    var keyHeld_Left = false;
    var keyHeld_Right = false;

    //Keypress?
    
      function keyPressed(evt) {
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_UP) {          
            keyHeld_Up = true;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) {
 
            keyHeld_Down = true;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_LEFT) {
          keyHeld_Left = true;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_RIGHT) {
          keyHeld_Right = true;
        }
          
          //prevents page from scrolling when arrow keys are pressed
          evt.preventDefault();
      }
          
      //Key Released?   
    
      function keyReleased(evt) {
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_UP) {          
            keyHeld_Up = false;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) {
 
            keyHeld_Down = false;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_LEFT) {
          keyHeld_Left = false;
        }
          
        if(evt.keyCode == KEY_RIGHT) {
          keyHeld_Right = false;
        }
          
      }
    
    //Initialize Canvas and Game Loop
       
    window.onload = function() {
    console.log("Is this thing on?");
        canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        var framesPerSecond = 30;
        setInterval(function() {
            
            drawObjects();
            movePlayer();
            damageTest();
            
        }, 1000/framesPerSecond);
    
    }        
    
   // Drawing function 
    
   function colorRect(x,y, width,height, color, health) {
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.color = color;
       this.health = health;
       
       this.update = function() {
           this.draw();
       }
       
       this.draw = function() {
          canvasContext.beginPath();
          canvasContext.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
          canvasContext.fillStyle = this.color;
          canvasContext.fill();
          canvasContext.closePath();
       }
    };
     
    // Creating Objects
    var Screen = new colorRect( 0, 0, 600, 480, 'black', 0);
    var Player = new colorRect( PLAYER_X, PLAYER_Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT, 'red', PLAYER_HEALTH);
    var Box = new colorRect( 200, 200, 30, 30, 'green', 0);
    var Spike = new colorRect( 300, 300, 25, 25, 'white', 0);

    // Drawing Objects
    
    function drawObjects() {
            Screen.update();
            Spike.update();
            Player.update();
            Box.update();
            
    }

    //Collision Test
    
    function collides( a, b ) {
     return a.x < b.x + b.width && 
            a.x + a.width > b.x &&
            a.y < b.y + b.height &&
            a.y + a.height > b.y;
    }

    //Movement based on keypress events
    
   function movePlayer() { 

      if(collides( Player, Box ) === false) {
         if(keyHeld_Up) {      
            Player.y -= 2;            
      }
       
       
          if(keyHeld_Down) {
             Player.y += 2;
      }
                    
          if(keyHeld_Left) {
             Player.x -= 2;
      }
             
          if(keyHeld_Right) {
             Player.x += 2;
      } 

      }
       
   

   }
    
    //Testing Collision for damage
    
    function damageTest() {
        
        if(collides( Player, Spike ) === true) {
            Player.health -= 1; 
        }
        
        //Displaying Health in <body>
        
        document.getElementById("Health").innerHTML = "Health: " + Player.health; 
    }
   
    

</script>
        

</body>

</html>
```

The code I made stops the player in its tracks completely when hitting the box, but you could create individual collision circumstances for when objects collide on each side of another object, and use those to detect collision.

I hope this helped! If you have any questions regarding this code, just ask! (To run code snippet you might want to go full screen and click inside canvas)

Comment: To stop the player, using this code above, I used the collision detection function in order to test if the player could move or not. I hope this clarified my answer.